# In ElasticSearch how to filter result set on certain word?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch. I have built a database of different electronic items and its accessories. From that Database I am trying to search all the laptops, notebooks and computers using item name. However it also returns some accessories like laptop backpack or laptop case etc. I am using must_not clause in query but it doesn't really eliminate unnecessary result. Can someone advise on what I am doing wrong? Or how should I improve my query listed below??

```
30 res = es.search( index=Index, body={
 31         "query": {
 32             "filtered": {
 33                 "query": {
 34                     "match_all": {}
 35                     },
 36                 "filter": {
 37                     "bool": {
 38                         "must": [
 39                             {
 40                                 "terms": {
 41                                     "name": [
 42                                         "laptop","notebook","computer"
 43                                         ],
 44                                     "execution" : "or"
 45                                     }
 46                                 }
 47                             ],
 48                         "must_not": [
 49                             {
 50                                 "term": {
 51                                     "name": "Backpack"
 52                                     }
 53                                 }
 54                             ]
 55                         }
 56                     }
 57                 }
 58             }
 59 
 60           })
```

Thanks in advance.
Please note that I am trying to use python and elasticsearch python library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put your documents to the index, ElasticSearch applies analyzer to strign values which splits your input into terms and applies some filters to it. It seems that default analyzer also applies `lowercase` token filter to your input, so the result tokens are in lower case. You can try to use query with lowercase term like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "name": [
                                    "laptop",
                                    "notebook",
                                    "computer"
                                ],
                                "execution": "or"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "name": "backpack"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can try to use `match` query instead of `term` query

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "name": [
                                    "laptop",
                                    "notebook",
                                    "computer"
                                ],
                                "execution": "or"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "name": "Backpack"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second option might work slightly slower but if your keywords are not tokenized terms, this will give an expected result for other inputs

Comment: Thanks Random. Really appreciate this help. You made my day.